# How to install 3rd party module for postgres pl/python?

Tags: postgresql, plpython

I need to import a 3rd party module inside my pl/python function.
It seems pl/python uses an internal python that does not have any 3rd party modules.

I get this kind of error:

```
ERROR:  PL/Python: PL/Python function "to_tsvector_luc" failed
DETAIL:  <type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named lucene

********** Error **********

ERROR: PL/Python: PL/Python function "to_tsvector_luc" failed
SQL state: XX000
Detail: <type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named lucene
```

How do I install the module into pl/python, so that I can import it from inside my stored procedure code?

Comment: As you found out `plpython3u` uses the system Python and system `site-packages` not the local(user) packages. It makes sense as it running in a system service, the Postgres server.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

pl/python has access to the all the modules that the normal Python interpreter would have as long as they are in the `$PYTHONPATH` on the server (and the user that runs the postgres service). Does `import lucene` work if you run it in the Python interpreter on the server?

If your module is installed somewhere else (e.g. not dist-packages etc.), then you would need to edit your `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/environment` (adjust to your PostgreSQL version) file on the server and add something like `PYTHONPATH='<path to your module>'`.

Comment: `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/environment` only appears to be a thing on Ubuntu, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595683/postgresql-environment-file-on-mac-osx)

Comment: And about `plpython3u`? (today using with pg13)...  1. Checking the path of module by `print(a_module.__file__)`, is it?   2. the [`$PYTHONPATH` ](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpython-envar.html) seems same for Python3, is it?  3. But about many modules?  And a module installed by `pip` but at `/home/myUser` ... Please  expand answer about modern (2021) details

Answer (score 19):

Since modifying PYTHONPATH of postgres user will likely need a server restart, it's somewhat easier to add the path from within Python, via

```
from sys import path
path.append( '/path/to/your/module' )
```

Comment: **Not working**...  Need to  add `import moduleX` clause?  about  path, is the folder where you see `__init__.py `, by  `print(a_module.__file__)`?  I installed chevron by `pip` and obtained a user-area path, `/home/myUser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/chevron/` , it is valid? No PostgreSQL server access-to-path  problem?

Answer (score 5):

For me, it was about knowing which version Python Postgres was
   looking at and then installing to the /local/lib directory and NOT
   .local directory which is not recognised in Postgres.

In Postgres, created this function to identify the Python version it
   was using:
.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION python_version()
    RETURNS pg_catalog.text AS $BODY$

    import sys
    plpy.info(sys.version)    
    return 'finish'
    $BODY$
LANGUAGE plpython3u VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER
```

Execute function using the following:

```
select python_version()
```

In Python:

```
import sys
sys.version
```

Both the script and Python said:
**INFO:  3.7.3 (default, Aug 20 2019, 17:04:43)**

pip3 install placed the library into this directory:
/home/username/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages

To make the package available to ALL users (including Postgres).
I used umask:

```
sudo su
cd ~
umask 022
pip3 install <package name>
```

NOTE: The package installs in:
/usr/local/lib# cd python3.7/dist-packages
NOT in
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages#

Comment: Yes, need ugly *pip3* procedure with  *sudor* and `unmask 022`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the 43 pl/python has access to the all the modules that the normal Python interpreter would have as long as they are in the **Pythonpath** on the server and user that is using **PostgreSQL**.

If your module is installed somewhere else (e.g. packages), then you would need to edit your /src/postgresql/9.1/main/environment (adjust to your PostgreSQL version) file on the server and add something like **Pythonpath**=>*'path to your module'**.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 22.04:

- Install your module: `sudo pip install foo`.
- Find out where your python stores installed modules. For me it was `/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/` - where obviously `python3.10` is your installed python version. The command `pip3 show <your package name here>` should help you out, if your path is different. E.g.: `pip3 show numpy`.
- Now, you need to change the permissions to your module files, because postgres is running as `postgres` user, but the files of your module will belong to `root`. You should do: `sudo chmod -R 755 <path to your module>`.  E.g.: `sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/test_module`.

And now your module should be working.