# PostgreSQL PL/Python: call stored procedure in virtualenv

Tags: python, postgresql, stored-procedures, virtualenv, plpython

When I call a PostgreSQL PL/Python stored procedure in my Python application, it seems to be executed in a separate process running as user `postgres`. So far, this only had the side effect that I had to make my logfile writable for both myself and the database user, so application and stored procedure can both write to it.

Now however, I started using [`virtualenv`](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html) and added a number of `.pth` files to my `~/.virtualenvs/virt_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` folder that add the paths to my modules to the Python path.

When the stored procedure is executed, user `postgres` is not in the same virtual environment as I am, so the stored procedure does not find my modules. I can modify `PYTHONPATH` in the [global PostgreSQL environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032293/how-to-install-3rd-party-module-for-postgres-pl-python), but I have to change that every time I switch virtual environments - which is kinda against the purpose of virtualenv...

How can I extend the Python path for stored procedures ?

**UPDATE**:

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11019169/217844) has been asked and the resolution there was to modify the PYTHONPATH environment variable in Postgres; however, it seems that [there is no standard way to specify environment variables for PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10119937/217844); at least, it is not a viable solution on Mac OSX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to do it, as it turns out. Since version 1.6 or there abouts, virtualenv comes with a script `activate_this.py`, which can be used to set up an existing interpreter to access that particular virtualenv.

```
exec(open('/Some/VirtualEnv/Directory/myvirtualenv/bin/activate_this.py').read(), 
dict(__file__='/Some/VirtualEnv/Directory/myvirtualenv/bin/activate_this.py'))
```

And as a fully-realized plpython function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION workon(venv text)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
    import os
    import sys

    if sys.platform in ('win32', 'win64', 'cygwin'):
        activate_this = os.path.join(venv, 'Scripts', 'activate_this.py')
    else:
        if not os.environ.has_key('PATH'):
            import subprocess
            p=subprocess.Popen('echo -n $PATH', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
            (mypath,err) = p.communicate()
            os.environ['PATH'] = mypath

        activate_this = os.path.join(venv, 'bin', 'activate_this.py')

    exec(open(activate_this).read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpythonu VOLATILE
```

(The extra PATH mungery is needed since by default PATH isn't available in plpython os.environ - 
activate_this.py has a [fix checked in](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/commit/6803ab939951245c3b734762f30e34fda4974012) that should roll w/ the next point release (which should be 1.11.7 or 1.12)

( taken mostly from https://gist.github.com/dmckeone/69334e2d8b27f586414a )

Comment: I am not sure that this virtualenv paths remains active across multiple plpython calls, because the interpreter is new on every call. I suppose you are assuming we call workon() from all plpython methods at the very start?

Comment: Actually, within a session (db connection) all plpython functions share an interpreter, though they get a fresh execution state (barring the global GD data-sharing dictionary) - you do not start a new interpreter for each query. Don't call it multiple times, the sys.path will continue to grow

Answer (score 2):

Normally I'd say it's not really a good idea but you may be able to follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205064/is-there-a-way-to-change-another-processs-environment-variables).

What you could do is run multiple instances of PostgreSQL with different environments to allow for various `PYTHONPATH` settings.