# Can python venv be used with plpython3u for postgresql?

Tags: python, postgresql, postgres-plpython

I would like plpython3u to use a virtual environment for python. I have seen some (old and not particularly clear) instructions for virtualenv at [PostgreSQL PL/Python: call stored procedure in virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586331/postgresql-pl-python-call-stored-procedure-in-virtualenv). However I havent seen anything for python venv. Can this be done and if so, how can it be done? Thanks.

CCl.

Answer (score 3):

If you only need one `venv` environment for PL/Python, you can simply modify `ExecStart` in the PostggreSQL unit file to load `venv` `activate` script.

Below is excerpted from the [PostgreSQL 14 systemd unit file of PGDG YUM installation](https://yum.postgresql.org/) (My `venv` ls located at `/var/lib/pgsql/plpython/`).

```
ExecStartPre=/usr/pgsql-14/bin/postgresql-14-check-db-dir ${PGDATA}
#ExecStart=/usr/pgsql-14/bin/postmaster -D ${PGDATA}
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "source /var/lib/pgsql/plpython/bin/activate && /usr/pgsql-14/bin/postmaster -D ${PGDATA}"
```

Note that you need to copy the unit file `postgresql-14.service` from `/usr/lib/systemd/system/` to `/etc/systemd/system/` and execute `systemctl daemon-reload` to take effect.

Then you can [check `venv` with the `pkg_resources` module](https://www.activestate.com/resources/quick-reads/how-to-list-installed-python-packages/) inside PL/Python anonymous block (I install `pyyaml` in my `venv` environment).

```
postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u ;
CREATE EXTENSION
postgres=# DO $$
import pkg_resources
installed_packages = pkg_resources.working_set
installed_packages_list = sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version)
   for i in installed_packages])
plpy.notice(installed_packages_list)
$$ LANGUAGE plpython3u;
NOTICE:  ['pip==9.0.3', 'pyyaml==5.4.1', 'setuptools==39.2.0']
DO
postgres=#
```