# How can I use venv version of python for plpython3u on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, postgresql, ubuntu

[The past post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62551455/can-python-venv-be-used-with-plpython3u-for-postgresql) has provided a perfect solution for RedHat-based distributions. So, I gave it a try on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS the same way. I edited /usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service:

```
# comment out the original ExecStart
#ExecStart=-/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect %i start
ExecStart=-/bin/bash -c "source /opt/python/venv/bin/activate && /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect %i start"
```

Then, I restarted the service.

However, that didn't work as I had expected. I checked the python path by executing this.

```
do $$

import sys

plpy.info(sys.executable)
plpy.info(sys.path)
plpy.info(sys.prefix)

$$ language plpython3u;
```

The result shows that the python interpreter is not that of venv.

```
INFO:  
INFO:  ['/usr/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.10', '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
INFO:  /usr
```

Please tell me how to enable venv for plpython3u on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Thank you.