# PostgreSQL environment file on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, postgresql, environment-variables

PostgreSQL seems to have an environment file that allows settings environment variables. On Linux (Kubuntu 11.10 in my case), it is located at e.g. `/etc/postgresql/8.4/main/environment` and empty by default, apart from a few helpful comments.

On Mac OSX Lion, the file does not seem to exist: I would expect it at e.g. `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.0/data/` as that's where all the other configuration files are, but it is not there - and if I create it, it does not seem to be used.

How can I set environment variables for the PostgreSQL server on Mac OSX ?

Comment: I can't find anything about such a file in the official Postgres docs, so I believe it's a Ubuntu/Debian artifact.

Comment: What should these envitionment variables contain? If you need to change settings, the config is probably better, if you need to change settings based on database/table/... there are specific settings for it.

Comment: how do you set PYTHONPATH in the config ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard way to specify environment variables for PostgreSQL, I assume that file is `Kubuntu` specific.

What I did to ease my life was copying approach used by ORACLE:

- I have `/etc/pgtab` file on each server where I run PostgreSQL databases;
- I specify each cluster I run on a single line in the `/etc/pgtab`;
- I've created a script `pgenv` which based on the `/etc/pgtab` shows the menu of clusters (in case there're more then just one) and initialize all `PATH`s and variables.

It works on my MacBookPro and on all Linux and HP-UX based servers.